# How to get rid of not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent'

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is the react typescript project. Because I am using 3rd party library.

I am manipulating the dom element directly

```
const modal = jsonEditBtns[i].querySelector('.je-modal') as HTMLElement;
        const paste: HTMLButtonElement = document.createElement('button');
        paste.textContent = 'paste';
        paste.classList.add(
          'btn',
          'btn-sm',
          'btn-primary',
          'mr-2',
          'my-1',
          'json-editor-btn-paste',
          'json-editor-btntype-paste'
        );
        if (paste && typeof paste !== null && paste.onclick !== null) {
          paste.onclick(() => { // Error coming from onClick event handler
            console.log('hello');
          });
        }
```

Error Log

```
Argument of type '() => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent'.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently calling the `onclick` event handler on your `paste` object. This handler naturally expects a parameter of type `MouseEvent` to be passed into it.

From what I can tell you really want to assign a new handler to the `onclick` property, like `paste.onclick = () => console.log('hello')`.